# How can I find Big-O notation for my loops?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I am having trouble finding out the Big-O notation for this fragment of code.
I need to find the notation for both for loops.

```
public static int fragment(int n)
{
  int sum = 0;

  for (int i = n; i >= 1; i /= 2)
  {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j *= 3)
    {
      sum++;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm inclined to say it's `O(n log n)`... the outer loop is `log n` and the inner one is just `n`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol not at all. Inner loop is `log(i)`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev How so? If anything, it's `i/3`, which is just `i`... and if `i` is `log n`, then... erm... I have no idea XD

Comment: Ah, so I was almost there! I was thinking "if `i` is `log n` then the result would be `(log n)^2`", but I thought I'd be saying something silly XD

Answer (score 3):

Think of the two loops separately:

First lets consider `for(int i=n; i>=1; i/=2)` on each iteration the value of `i` will be divided by 2 until it reaches a value less than `1`. Therefor the number of iterations N will be equal to the number of times you should divide `i` by `2` before it gets less than 1. There is a well known function representing this number - `log(n)`.

Now lets consider the inner loop. `for(int j=1;j<=i; j*=3)`. Here you multiply j by 3 until it becomes more than `i`. If you think a bit this is exactly the same number of iterations that the following slight modification of the first cycle would do: `for(int j=i; j>=1; j/=3)`. And with exactly the same explanation we have the same function(but with a different base - 3). Problem here is that the number of iterations is depending on i.

So now we have total complexity being:

log<sub>3</sub>(n) + log<sub>3</sub>(n/2) + log<sub>3</sub>(n/4) ... + log<sub>3</sub>(1) =

log<sub>3</sub>(n) + log<sub>3</sub>(n) - log<sub>3</sub>(2) + log<sub>3</sub>(n) .... - log<sub>3</sub>(2<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup>) =

log<sub>3</sub>(n) * log<sub>2</sub> (n) - log<sub>3</sub>(2) - 2 * log<sub>3</sub>(2) - ... log<sub>2</sub>(n) * log<sub>3</sub>(2) =

log<sub>3</sub>(n) * log<sub>2</sub> (n) - log<sub>3</sub>(2) * (1 + 2 + ... log<sub>2</sub>) =

log<sub>3</sub>(n) * log<sub>2</sub> (n) - log<sub>3</sub>(2) * (log<sub>2</sub>(n) * (log<sub>2</sub>(n) + 1)) / 2 =

log<sub>2</sub> (n) * (log<sub>3</sub>(n) - log<sub>3</sub>(2) * (log<sub>2</sub>(n) + 1) / 2) =

log<sub>2</sub> (n) * (log<sub>3</sub>(n) -   (log<sub>3</sub>(n) + log<sub>3</sub>(2)) / 2) =

(log<sub>2</sub> (n) * log<sub>3</sub>(n)) / 2 - (log<sub>2</sub> (n) * log<sub>3</sub>(2)) / 2

Calculation is bit tricky and I use a few properties of logarithm. However the final conclusion is that the cycles are of the complexity `O(log(n)^2)`(remember you can ignore base of a logarithm).

Answer (score 1):

To formally infer the time complexity, using sigma notation is a suitable approach:

[image]

WolframAlpha helped me to with summations closed-form formulas.

For logarithms, you may check the last slide of [this document](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt), where Dr. Jauhar explains the logarithmic loops.

Comment: Actually, this is Omega(log(n)^2).